# Calculating age from birthdate year to current date in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Can anyone help me here? I don't have any idea why my code for calculating age is not working. Thank you for the response.

```
int year = Convert.ToInt32(passportApplicant.DateOfBirth.Year)  - Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.Year);
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to have any issues, However what is the datatype for passportApplicant.DateOfBirth.Year. Even if its smaller, the result should be a negative integer.

Comment: Do not understand the problem? so what is your input, what you get output and what you desire, please explain

Comment: Are you checked the null value, as your variable is nullable.

Answer (score 0):

year should be returning a int value already no need to convert it.

also you should be subtracting nows time from the date of birth time (biggertime - smallertime)

your statement should look like this:

```
    int year = DateTime.Now.Year - passportApplicant.DateOfBirth.Year
    // 2020 - 2000 = 20 years old
```

or this gets you the exact year of birth

```
    // this subtracts the passports year, month, and day from the time now
    // leaving you with the difference between date born and the time now
    int year = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-passportApplicant.DateOfBirth.Year).AddMonths(-passportApplicant.DateOfBirth.Month).AddDays(-passportApplicant.DateOfBirth.Month.day)).Year;
```

Hope this helps!

Edit:
little side note. try using datetime.UtcNow whenever possible especially when saving to a database. only use the users datetime.now when displaying. it will help you big time down the road as timezone will throw off everything